# Последний элемент в GridView как первый

Tags: android, gridview

Всем привет, во время изучение туториала с `GridView` возник вопрос, как последний элемент (картинку\текст) установить в первый элемент используя `BaseAdapter`.
Как менять скажем длину массива для отображения в том же `GridView` или отображение той или иной картинки как превью я вроде разобрался. Попытки же приравнять последний элемент к первому или получить в getItem ни к чему не приводят. Буду благодарен любым подсказкам.

```
private Context mContext;

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1, R.drawable.sample_2, 
        R.drawable.sample_3, R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5, 
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        };

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mThumbIds.length; // длина массива
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mThumbIds[position]; // позиция картинки

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0; // id картинки
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[mThumbIds.length - 1]); //отвечает за отображение превью, не отвечает за положение картинки
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(120, 110));

    return imageView;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

В getView делайте проверку, является ли текущий position последним. Если да, то задавайте View точно такое же, как и для элемента с position 0.